# _layout view only showing on Home/Index MVC

Tags: html, model-view-controller, layout

I'm developing a website in which I have a main screen with a sidebar. This sidebar has to be in all the views of my site so I added it to _layout.cshtml.

But my surprise is that when I call p.e. Contacts controller, the view is empty, without any layout.

Things I've already done:

- **Checked _ViewStart.cshtml:**

  ```
  @{
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
  ```
- **Added that piece of code to the top of my Contacts view**

None of them seems to be working, any idea?

Comment: If you have set your Layout variable in `_ViewStart.cshtml`, then you don't need to set it again in your `Contacts.cshtml`

Comment: Can you put the code of both Contacts.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml?